# Wifi is getting disconnected when bluetooth device is connected in Ubuntu 20.04 for XPS 15 L502X laptop

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, dell, 20.04, xps

Wifi and Bluetooth not working simultaneously. When I am trying to connect BT speaker or any BT device then wifi is not working. Got software upates even after that it's not workng. find my debug info below and assist me with fixing this.

```
amit@Amit:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 11n_disable=8 bt_coex_active=1 power_save=0 swcrypto=1

    amit@Amit:~$ dmesg | grep iwl


[   18.091630] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'auto_agg' ignored
[   18.091632] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'swctypto' ignored
[   18.091945] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   19.616897] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   22.259449] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   22.259474] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   22.259475] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   22.259476] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
[   22.294877] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   22.320206] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   31.309671] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[   31.404403] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[  439.845754] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[  439.946407] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1

    amit@Amit:~$ sudo lshw -C network

[sudo] password for amit: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 34
       serial: ac:72:89:d0:eb:f2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-37-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:38 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 06
       serial: 84:8f:69:b6:09:0c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1804000-f1804fff memory:f1800000-f1803fff


    amit@Amit:~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:0941 HP, Inc X500 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    amit@Amit:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware



[    0.147887] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.180992] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   19.616897] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
amit@Amit:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)


    amit@Amit:~$ sudo lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1c4b] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df4] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
amit@Amit:~$ 

    amit@Amit:~$ iwconfig

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Papa Ko Bol Internet Lagaye"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F8:C4:F3:0D:C6:E0   
          Bit Rate=121.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-25 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:34  Invalid misc:138   Missed beacon:0

enp6s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

    amit@Amit:~$ rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
amit@Amit:~$ rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


After fun + f2 

    amit@Amit:~$ rfkill list

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

    amit@Amit:~$ iwconfig

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Papa Ko Bol Internet Lagaye"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F8:C4:F3:0D:C6:E0   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-25 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:74  Invalid misc:91   Missed beacon:0

enp6s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

    amit@Amit:~$ rfkill list

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


    amit@Amit:~$ lshw -C network

WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 34
       serial: ac:72:89:d0:eb:f2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-37-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:38 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 06
       serial: 84:8f:69:b6:09:0c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1804000-f1804fff memory:f1800000-f1803fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

    amit@Amit:~$ sudo lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1c4b] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df4] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)

    amit@Amit:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/messages

tail: cannot open '/var/log/messages' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining

    amit@Amit:~$ sudo lshw -businfo

Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
                              system         Dell System XPS L502X (System SKUNu
                              bus            0MY6GN
                              memory         128KiB BIOS
cpu@0                         processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.
                              memory         64KiB L1 cache
                              memory         256KiB L2 cache
                              memory         3MiB L3 cache
                              memory         8GiB System Memory
                              memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 M
                              memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 M
pci@0000:00:00.0              bridge         2nd Generation Core Processor Famil
pci@0000:00:01.0              bridge         Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Pr
pci@0000:01:00.0              display        GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
pci@0000:01:00.1              multimedia     GF108 High Definition Audio Control
pci@0000:00:02.0              display        2nd Generation Core Processor Famil
pci@0000:00:16.0              communication  6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
pci@0000:00:1a.0              bus            6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
usb@1             usb1        bus            EHCI Host Controller
usb@1:1                       bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
usb@1:1.4                     multimedia     Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2HDM
pci@0000:00:1b.0              multimedia     6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
pci@0000:00:1c.0              bridge         6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
pci@0000:00:1c.1              bridge         6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
pci@0000:03:00.0  wlp3s0      network        Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow P
pci@0000:00:1c.3              bridge         6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
pci@0000:04:00.0              bus            uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
usb@3             usb3        bus            xHCI Host Controller
usb@3:2                       input          HP X500 USB Optical Mouse
usb@4             usb4        bus            xHCI Host Controller
pci@0000:00:1c.4              bridge         6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
pci@0000:00:1c.5              bridge         6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
pci@0000:06:00.0  enp6s0      network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigab
pci@0000:00:1d.0              bus            6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
usb@2             usb2        bus            EHCI Host Controller
usb@2:1                       bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
usb@2:1.5                     communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
pci@0000:00:1f.0              bridge         HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller
pci@0000:00:1f.2  scsi0       storage        6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
scsi@0:0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           500GB WDC WD5000BPKT-7
scsi@0:0.0.0,1    /dev/sda1   volume         465GiB EXT4 volume
scsi@1:0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+-RW TS-L633J
pci@0000:00:1f.3              bus            6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
                              system         PnP device PNP0b00
                              generic        PnP device INT3f0d
                              input          PnP device PNP0303
                              generic        PnP device DLL050e
                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
                              power          DELL
amit@Amit:~$ 

    amit@Amit:~$ ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:8f:69:b6:09:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:72:89:d0:eb:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 258902sec preferred_lft 258902sec
    inet6 fe80::9231:43ca:10af:c6cd/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Please check and let me know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with exactly the same laptop model and network card.
It seems that our dual network-bt card is not able to avoid the interference with both interfaces, something that new cards can do by themselves (see this [guide](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi) in the Debian wiki for iwlwifi).

I found a solution in a bug report (see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/219057)), which also involved to create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and setting its content as: `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 auto_agg=0 swcrypto=1`.

If you already have some content in that file, you can overwrite it using:
`sudo echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 auto_agg=0 swcrypto=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Don't forget to reboot your laptop for changes to take effect.

I am using my laptop right know to write this while listening YT with my Bluetooth headphones, no issues so far. As a note, this issue happened to me both in Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: Hi, my bad, I edited my answer to clarify that the file only has that line and that I got no issues after editing it.